# On drop not working

Tags: javascript

Im trying to figure out how to make use of drag n drop, just added the draggable="true" on a element

```
<a draggable="true" href="#" title="just a test">test</a>
```

but cant make in drop on parent div, cant tell if its calling a error or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried inserting js to accept drop? here

```
ondragover="allowDrop(event);"
```

function allowDrop(x) { x.preventDefault(); }

Comment: how can i change the cursor in this move?